# Marker not displayed at intended coordinate on Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

I'm trying to retrieve latitude and longitude values from database in the previous activity and sent them using intent to this current activity. I have already converted them to double value and sending them as double in this activity. The retrieval from database is successful. However when I plot these coordinates using a marker, the default value of the `getDoubleExtra()` is being plotted and not the actual coordinates.

```
    public class MapsMarkerActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements OnMapReadyCallback {
String username11;
Double lat,lng;
GoogleMap mMap;
LatLng me;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_marker);
    Intent y=getIntent();
    username11=y.getStringExtra("username");
    lat=y.getDoubleExtra("lat",23.45);
    lng=y.getDoubleExtra("'lng",75.22);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap=googleMap;
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.852, 151.211);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)
            .title("Marker in Sydney"));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    googleMap.clear();
    me=new LatLng(lat,lng);
    col(mMap);
}
public void col(GoogleMap mMap){
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(me).title("Location of "+username11));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(me));
}
  }
```

The marker points at 23.45 lat and 75.22 instead of the value retrieved from the database.

What needs to be done to rectify this?

The code where I am calling the maps activity is below

```
    Intent u=new Intent(this,MapsMarkerActivity.class);
    u.putExtra("lat",lat);
    u.putExtra("lng",lng);
    u.putExtra("username",username11);
    startActivity(u);
```

And the parsing is as as given below, I am using volley to get a string which is the response.

```
    lat=Double.parseDouble(response);
```

Comment: Could you show the code where you are starting the `MapsMarkerActivity`?

Comment: Yes, i will update it

Comment: @antonio updated it.